# Solidity function does not return array of hashes to W3

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js, quorum

I have a Solidity method that gets a list of strings from my contract, hashes each string and returns an array of hashes. I tested this in Remix and it works well.

In development I'm calling this function from Node.js, but for some reason getting back `[object Object]` which does not contain an array of hashes.

I should add that my web3 provider is not Ethereum but Quorum's 7nodes example.

This is the Solidity function:

```
function getHashs(string id) public view returns (bytes32[]) {
    bytes32[] memory stringsToHash = getStrings(id);
    bytes32[] memory hashes = new bytes32[](5);

    for(uint i=0; i<=stringsToHash.length-1; i++) {
        bytes32 str = seeds[i];
        bytes32 hash = sha256(abi.encodePacked(seed));
        hashes[i] = hash;
    }

    return hashes;
}
```

This is the `w3` code:

```
function getHashes(id, contract, fromAccount, privateForNode) {

   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

       contract.methods.getHashs(id).send({from: fromAccount, gas: 150000000, privateFor: [privateForNode]})
       .then(hashes => {
           console.log("got hashes from node === ");
           console.log(hashes[0]); // this is 'undefined'
          resolve(hashes);
       },
       (error) => {
           reject(error);
       }).catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
       });

   })
   .catch((err) => {
      reject(err);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.send(...)`, you want `.call(...)`. The former broadcasts a transaction to the network, and the result is a transaction hash and ultimately (once the transaction has been mined) a transaction receipt. Transactions have no return value from the smart contract.

`.call(...)` is used for `view` functions. It computes the result of the function call locally (just on the node you're connected to) without sending a transaction, and it returns the result to you. No state changes occur in the blockchain, because no transaction was broadcast. `call`s require no gas.